# Problem building with Go go-bindata-assetfs: Command not found

Tags: go

I'm having problems trying to buil this code:
https://github.com/EmbarkStudios/wg-ui

It seems like it cannot find go-bindata-assetfs but I think all is installed correctly... I'm in Debian 10

```
go get github.com/go-bindata/go-bindata/...
go get github.com/elazarl/go-bindata-assetfs/...
go-bindata-assetfs -prefix ui/dist ui/dist
make: go-bindata-assetfs: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:23: assets] Error 12
```

Go is installed and its path appended to /etc/profile:

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin`

```
$ which go
/usr/local/go/bin/go
```

The Makefile:

```
# Parameters
GOCMD=go
GOBUILD=$(GOCMD) build
GOCLEAN=$(GOCMD) clean
GOGET=$(GOCMD) get
BINARY_NAME=wireguard-ui

.PHONY: build container ui assets

all: build

clean:
    $(GOCLEAN)
    rm -rf bin
    rm -rf ui/node_modules ui/dist

ui:
    cd ui && npm install && npm run build

assets:
    $(GOGET) github.com/go-bindata/go-bindata/...
    $(GOGET) github.com/elazarl/go-bindata-assetfs/...
    go-bindata-assetfs -prefix ui/dist ui/dist

build: ui assets
    CGO_ENABLED=0 $(GOBUILD) -o bin/$(BINARY_NAME) -v

build-amd64: ui assets
        CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 $(GOBUILD) -o bin/$(BINARY_NAME)-amd64 -v

build-armv5: ui assets
    CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=5 $(GOBUILD) -o bin/$(BINARY_NAME)-armv5 -v

build-armv6: ui assets
    CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=6 $(GOBUILD) -o bin/$(BINARY_NAME)-armv6 -v

build-armv7: ui assets
    CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=7 $(GOBUILD) -o bin/$(BINARY_NAME)-armv7 -v

container:
    docker build -t wireguard-ui .

run-dev:
    sudo ./bin/$(BINARY_NAME) --log-level=debug --dev-ui-server=http://localhost:5000

run-dev-ui:
    cd ui && npm run dev
```

Node version:

```
$ node -v
v12.18.3
```

Here is `go env`

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/debianuser/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/debianuser/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/home/debianuser/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/debianuser/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/home/debianuser/wireguard-ui/go.mod"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build504714797=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

Thanks for the attention

Comment: share `go env` output please.

Comment: added to the post, thanks

Comment: you did not set `GOBIN` env variable. You might also need to add this path to your PATH variable. Give it a try.

Comment: btw, i recommend using something like GVM to help you manage multiple versions. At least updating your go setup in future (every 6 months) will be super easy.

Comment: solved with `export GOBIN=$HOME/go/bin` env variable. Thanks, mh-cbon! I will take a look at GVM

Answer (score 2):

This works to me...

I the home folder adds a new folder called go that I do is add this

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/golang/go/bin:$HOME/go/bin
```

I have installed go in /opt/golang/ to have access to the binaries I also add the bin path for the addons I hope this will solve the issue for you too